# How to pass a const char[] array as constexpr to a template?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++20

In order to explore C++ abstraction power, I took this example from [Jarod42 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59473757/4934640) on this other question [How to stop template recursion while using parameter deduction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472892/how-to-stop-template-recursion-while-using-parameter-deduction):

```cpp
#define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)

template<int PathLength, int I = PathLength>
constexpr const int findlastslash(const char (&path)[PathLength])
{
    if constexpr (I == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (path[I - 1] == '/' || path[I - 1] == '\\') {
            return I;
        }
        return findlastslash<PathLength, I - 1>(path);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    STATIC_ASSERT( findlastslash( "c/test" ) == 2 );
}
```

This this example, I am trying to improve it by removing the constexpr parameter **`I`** from the function **`findlastslash_impl`**. I would like to remove the **`I`** constexpr parameter because it makes the recursion always go from **`const char[]`** string size down to 0: (compiling it with **`clang`** and using special flags shows us the template expansions)

**`clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp > main.exe`**

```cpp
template <int PathLength, int I = PathLength> 
constexpr const int findlastslash(const char (&path)[PathLength]) {
    if (I == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (path[I - 1] == '/' || path[I - 1] == '\\') {
            return I;
        }
        return findlastslash<PathLength, I - 1>(path);
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<7, 7>(const char (&path)[7]) {
    if (7 == 0)
        ;
    else {
        if (path[7 - 1] == '/' || path[7 - 1] == '\\') {
            return 7;
        }
        return findlastslash<7, 7 - 1>(path);
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<7, 6>(const char (&path)[7]) {
    if (6 == 0)
        ;
    else {
        if (path[6 - 1] == '/' || path[6 - 1] == '\\') {
            return 6;
        }
        return findlastslash<7, 6 - 1>(path);
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<7, 5>(const char (&path)[7]) {
    if (5 == 0)
        ;
    else {
        if (path[5 - 1] == '/' || path[5 - 1] == '\\') {
            return 5;
        }
        return findlastslash<7, 5 - 1>(path);
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<7, 4>(const char (&path)[7]) {
    if (4 == 0)
        ;
    else {
        if (path[4 - 1] == '/' || path[4 - 1] == '\\') {
            return 4;
        }
        return findlastslash<7, 4 - 1>(path);
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<7, 3>(const char (&path)[7]) {
    if (3 == 0)
        ;
    else {
        if (path[3 - 1] == '/' || path[3 - 1] == '\\') {
            return 3;
        }
        return findlastslash<7, 3 - 1>(path);
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<7, 2>(const char (&path)[7]) {
    if (2 == 0)
        ;
    else {
        if (path[2 - 1] == '/' || path[2 - 1] == '\\') {
            return 2;
        }
        return findlastslash<7, 2 - 1>(path);
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<7, 1>(const char (&path)[7]) {
    if (1 == 0)
        ;
    else {
        if (path[1 - 1] == '/' || path[1 - 1] == '\\') {
            return 1;
        }
        return findlastslash<7, 1 - 1>(path);
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<7, 0>(const char (&path)[7]) {
    if (0 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    static_assert(findlastslash("c/test") == 2, 
            "findlastslash( \"c/test\" ) == 2");
}
```

Then, if convert the function parameter **`path`** to a constexpr, I can remove the **`I`** constexpr parameter and I am allowed to only expand the **`findlastslash_impl`** function recursion exactly to the location of the last slash instead of always going from **`const char[]`** string size down to 0.

Questions like [Template Non-Type argument, C++11, restriction for string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763443/template-non-type-argument-c11-restriction-for-string-literals) are just another question saying I cannot do it and suggests another hack. An answer to this question would may be written when the C++20 or C++23 is released with either one of these proposals:

1. ["String literals as non-type template parameters"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0424r2.pdf)
2. ["Class Types in Non-Type Template Parameters"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r0.pdf)

It is common to find something like this bellow, which works fine: ([Passing an array by reference to template function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163469/passing-an-array-by-reference-to-template-function-in-c))

```cpp
template<class T>
T sum_array(T (&a)[10], int size)
{ ...
```

But I would like to do something like this bellow instead, to be able to use the array in a **`if constexpr`**:

```cpp
template<class T, T (&a)[10]>
T sum_array(int size)
{ ...
```

Here, I got an example I am trying to apply this concept:

```cpp
#define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)

template< int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char (path)[PathLength] >
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr (path[PathIndex - 1] == '/' || path[PathIndex - 1] == '\\') {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    STATIC_ASSERT( findlastslash< 6, 6, "c/test" >() == 2 );
}
```

Compiling it with **`C++17`** standard, I got the compiler saying: **`error: ‘"c/test"’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char*’ because string literals can never be used in this context`**

How can I pass an **`const char[]`** array as a constexpr to **`findlastslash()`**?

---

Initially I had tried passing the **`const char[]`** array as a reference:

```cpp
template< int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char (&path)[PathLength] >
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
```

Leading the compiler to throw the errors:

1. **`error: ‘const char (& path)[7]’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char (&)[7]’ because a reference variable does not have a constant address`**
2. **`note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'path'`**

---

These are the compiler errors for the first example trying to use the `const char[]` array as a template parameter reference: **`template< int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char (&path)[PathLength] >`**

1. **`g++ -o main.exe --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp`**

   ```
   test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
   test_debugger.cpp:14:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘findlastslash<6, 6, "c/test">()’
        STATIC_ASSERT( findlastslash< 6, 6, "c/test" >() == 2 );
                                                       ^
   test_debugger.cpp:1:42: note: in definition of macro ‘STATIC_ASSERT’
    #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:4:21: note: candidate: template<int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char* path> constexpr const int findlastslash()
    constexpr const int findlastslash()
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:4:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
   test_debugger.cpp:14:52: error: ‘"c/test"’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char*’ because string literals can never be used in this context
        STATIC_ASSERT( findlastslash< 6, 6, "c/test" >() == 2 );
                                                       ^
   test_debugger.cpp:1:42: note: in definition of macro ‘STATIC_ASSERT’
    #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
   ```
2. **`clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp > main.exe`**

   ```
   test_debugger.cpp:14:20: error: no matching function for call to 'findlastslash'
       STATIC_ASSERT( findlastslash< 6, 6, "c/test" >() == 2 );
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:1:42: note: expanded from macro 'STATIC_ASSERT'
   #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:4:21: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'path'
   constexpr const int findlastslash()
                       ^
   1 error generated.
   ```

---

## Update

After I tried to couple with what **`C++ 17`** could offer, this is my code:

```cpp
template<int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char (path)[PathLength]>
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr( PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\' ) {
        return PathIndex;
    }

    return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
}

constexpr const char path[] = "c/test";

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    static_assert( findlastslash< 6, 6, path >() == 2, "Fail!" );
}
```

Which miserably fails with:

**`clc g++ -o main.exe --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp`**

```
test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
test_debugger.cpp:15:5: error: static assertion failed: Fail!
     static_assert( findlastslash< 6, 6, path >() == 2, "Fail!" );
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr const int findlastslash() [with int PathIndex = -898; int PathLength = 6; const char* path = (& path)]’:
test_debugger.cpp:8:58:   recursively required from ‘constexpr const int findlastslash() [with int PathIndex = 1; int PathLength = 6; const char* path = (& path)]’
test_debugger.cpp:8:58:   required from here
test_debugger.cpp:8:58: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
     return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
compilation terminated.
```

Even using a **`if constexpr`**, C++ cannot stop the recursion by itself checking the `PathIndex` parameter.

Some related questions:

1. [C++11 Local static values not working as template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966901/c11-local-static-values-not-working-as-template-arguments)
2. [Template on address of variable with static storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946089/template-on-address-of-variable-with-static-storage)

Comment: Related to: [Passing a string literal as a parameter to a C++ template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033110/passing-a-string-literal-as-a-parameter-to-a-c-template-class)

Comment: You can’t *ever* use a function parameter as a constant expression.  Why is this a surprise here?

Comment: @DavisHerring, The surprise is that I cannot pass the **`const char[]`** array as a template parameter (not function parameter). Following the my linked question, we see that C++ will maybe only allow it when the **`c++20`** is released.

Comment: Does this answer your (new) question? [Template Non-Type argument, C++11, restriction for string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763443/template-non-type-argument-c11-restriction-for-string-literals)

Comment: Your question doesn’t mention any of that or have the right version tags for it—it doesn’t even say “string literal” except in the error message, and there are other `const char[…]` objects for which the answer is different.  Please edit again, **reducing** the question to *one* clear point.  If you’re after an answer from C++23, you need to wait a couple of years before asking (but there is a non-trivial C++20 answer to *certain* variations on this theme).

Comment: @user: Is this question about arrays in general, `const char[]` specifically, or string literals in particular? Because those are three different questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas, it is about the c-style arrays **`const char[]`** as **`constexpr`** strings with **`function<int, "string">()`**

Comment: @user: That still kind of misses the point. Is it *especially* important that the type be `const char[]`? Is it important that this `function` takes *only* a string literal, rather than any `constexpr` string which might be generated by any `constexpr` process?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I edited the question explaining the reasons.

Comment: @user: "*I would like to remove the `I` constexpr parameter*" So... why are you still trying to use recursion? To remove the `I` template parameter means you want to turn the recursive implementation into iteration. Recursion *does not work* if you remove the argument that defines the termination of the recursive algorithm.

Comment: @user: Also, this explanation only raises more questions. How does your question about passing a string literal/`const char[]`/array as a template parameter relate to some function that takes a string as a regular parameter? I fail to see the connection here. In particular: "*it makes the recursion always go from const char[] string size down to 0*." Why exactly does that *matter*?

Comment: @NicolBolas, see the code example after the text **`Here, I got an example I am trying to apply this concept`**. There I had removed the **`I`** recursive parameter and had added **`const char (path)[PathLength]`** in the place of it. Now look at the body of the recursive function and compare it with the original one at the beginning of the question.

Comment: @user: You're still missing the question. Why are you trying to implement it that way, rather than the obvious, non-recursive, non-string-template-parameter way that definitely works? Why do you want to turn a function that takes a string by function parameter into a function that takes a string by template parameter? That's the part that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NicolBolas, to explore how much I can go deep into C++ inner workings without breaking into some limitation. Sadly we just see we cannot pass **`const char[]`** as  template constexpr parameters. On the proposal paper ["String literals as non-type template parameters"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0424r2.pdf) you will see more real and concrete examples of a real world usage for things like **`function<"myconstchar">()`**. My initial example here is just a silly experiment to see how much deep the rabbit hole goes. Sadly it did not go much deep.

Comment: @user: You certainly **can** have `const char (&)[]` template parameters, with or without a size.  Your terminology is very confusing: there is no template parameter that isn’t “constexpr”.  Are you just trying to ask what *C++20* does to “allow” string literals as template arguments?  If so, please **say** so (in fewer than 300 words)!

Comment: @DavisHerring, My question was bellow 300 words when I fist posted, but comments asking more questions kept coming. I cannot have **`const char (&)[]`** as template parameter (constexpr). There are two examples on my question where I tried to do so and the compiler throw right in my face: 1. **`error: ‘"c/test"’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char*’ because string literals can never be used in this context`**; 2 **`error: ‘const char (& path)[7]’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const char (&)[7]’ because a reference variable does not have a constant address`**.

Comment: @user: Once you figure out what you’re asking about is when you should shorten it.  You certainly can have that parameter; you just can’t pass a string literal (or a local variable) as an argument for it.  (Note that `const char[n]` as a parameter, template or otherwise, represents only a pointer, which might or might not be useful.)

Comment: I wrote an answer which shows how it could be done with the C++ standard as of **`C++ 17`** and how I would expect to be the best way to handle/write this code with an fictitious **`C++`** standard which would allow to directly use a template constexpr as **`function<"string">()`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo. I managed to make something to work with what the **`C++ 17`** standard allow us:

```cpp
template<int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char (path)[PathLength]>
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr( PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\' ) {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    static constexpr const char path[] = "c/test";
    static_assert( findlastslash< 6, 7, path >() == 1, "Fail!" );
}
```

Which expands to this:

**`clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp > main.exe`**

```cpp
template <int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char (path)[PathLength]> 
constexpr const int findlastslash() 
{
    if (PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\') {
        return PathIndex;
    } else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<6, 7, &path>() 
{
    if (6 < 1 || path[6] == '/' || path[6] == '\\');
    else {
        return findlastslash<6 - 1, 7, path>();
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<5, 7, &path>() 
{
    if (5 < 1 || path[5] == '/' || path[5] == '\\');
    else {
        return findlastslash<5 - 1, 7, path>();
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<4, 7, &path>() 
{
    if (4 < 1 || path[4] == '/' || path[4] == '\\');
    else {
        return findlastslash<4 - 1, 7, path>();
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<3, 7, &path>() 
{
    if (3 < 1 || path[3] == '/' || path[3] == '\\');
    else {
        return findlastslash<3 - 1, 7, path>();
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<2, 7, &path>() 
{
    if (2 < 1 || path[2] == '/' || path[2] == '\\');
    else {
        return findlastslash<2 - 1, 7, path>();
    }
}

template<> 
constexpr const int findlastslash<1, 7, &path>() 
{
    if (1 < 1 || path[1] == '/' || path[1] == '\\') {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    static constexpr const char path[] = "c/test";
    static_assert(findlastslash<6, 7, path>() == 1, "Fail!");
}
```

While this is not the ideal solution, this is something which "works" with the **`C++`** available today.

The best answer would be the `C++` standard allowing us to write a code which can be easily maintainable like this:

```cpp
template< const char (path)[PathLength], int PathIndex >
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr (path[PathIndex - 1] == '/' || path[PathIndex - 1] == '\\') {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
    }
}

template< const char (path)[PathLength] >
constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
{
    return findlastslash< path, PathLength >();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    static_assert( startfindlastslash< "c/test" >() == 1, "Fail" );
}
```

However, such nice code miserably fails with:

1. **`clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp > main.exe`**

   ```
   test_debugger.cpp:1:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PathLength'
   template< const char (path)[PathLength], int PathIndex >
                               ^
   test_debugger.cpp:4:23: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
       if constexpr (path[PathIndex - 1] == '/' || path[PathIndex - 1] == '\\') {
                     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:4:53: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
       if constexpr (path[PathIndex - 1] == '/' || path[PathIndex - 1] == '\\') {
                                                   ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:8:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PathLength'
           return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
                                               ^
   test_debugger.cpp:12:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PathLength'
   template< const char (path)[PathLength] >
                               ^
   test_debugger.cpp:15:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PathLength'
       return findlastslash< path, PathLength >();
                                   ^
   test_debugger.cpp:13:21: error: no return statement in constexpr function
   constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
                       ^
   test_debugger.cpp:19:20: error: no matching function for call to 'startfindlastslash'
       static_assert( startfindlastslash< "c/test" >() == 1, "Fail" );
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:13:21: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'path'
   constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
                       ^
   8 errors generated.
   ```
2. **`g++ -o main.exe --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp`**

   ```
   test_debugger.cpp:1:29: error: ‘PathLength’ was not declared in this scope
    template< const char (path)[PathLength], int PathIndex >
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘constexpr const int findlastslash()’:
   test_debugger.cpp:4:19: error: ‘path’ was not declared in this scope
        if constexpr (path[PathIndex - 1] == '/' || path[PathIndex - 1] == '\\') {
                      ^~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:8:45: error: ‘PathLength’ was not declared in this scope
            return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:8:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘PathIndex’
            return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                PathIndex
   test_debugger.cpp: At global scope:
   test_debugger.cpp:12:29: error: ‘PathLength’ was not declared in this scope
    template< const char (path)[PathLength] >
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘constexpr const int startfindlastslash()’:
   test_debugger.cpp:15:27: error: ‘path’ was not declared in this scope
        return findlastslash< path, PathLength >();
                              ^~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:15:33: error: ‘PathLength’ was not declared in this scope
        return findlastslash< path, PathLength >();
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
   test_debugger.cpp:19:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘startfindlastslash<"c/test">()’
        static_assert( startfindlastslash< "c/test" >() == 1, "Fail" );
                                                      ^
   test_debugger.cpp:13:21: note: candidate: template<<declaration error> > constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
    constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:13:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
   ```

---

Another example from [How to deduce the size of a compile time a const char string with C++ templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418505/how-to-deduce-the-size-of-a-compile-time-a-const-char-string-with-c-templates)

```cpp
constexpr unsigned int requires_inRange(unsigned int i, unsigned int len) {
    return i >= len ? throw i : i;
}

class StrWrap
{
    unsigned size_;
    const char * begin_;

public:
    template< unsigned N >
    constexpr StrWrap( const char(&arr)[N] ) : begin_(arr), size_(N - 1) {
        static_assert( N >= 1, "not a string literal");
    }

    constexpr char operator[]( unsigned i ) {
        return requires_inRange(i, size_), begin_[i];
    }

    constexpr operator const char *() {
        return begin_;
    }

    constexpr unsigned size() {
        return size_;
    }
};

constexpr unsigned count( StrWrap str, char c, unsigned i = 0, unsigned ans = 0 )
{
    return i == str.size() ? ans :
               str[i] == c ? count(str, c, i + 1, ans + 1) :
                             count(str, c, i + 1, ans);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    static_assert( count("dude", 'd' ) == 2, "d != 2" );
    return 0;
}
```